# testfor lapis lazuli anywhere in inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have searched everywhere but I can't find the command in 1.12!

I want to make it so when someone picks up lapis lazuli, I get a redstone signal.

I have tried `testfor @a {Inventory:{[Id:"minecraft:dye,Damage:4,Count:1"]}}`
But all it says is did not match required data structure!

Answer (score 5):

```
testfor @a {Inventory:{[Id:"minecraft:dye,Damage:4,Count:1"]}}
```

Inventory is a list of compound tags - `[{...},{...},{...},{...}]`. Currently you've got it as a compound tag with a list inside without a key, when everything inside a compound tag requires a key.

Fix that to get:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{Id:"minecraft:dye,Damage:4,Count:1"}]}
```

Next, `id` needs a lowercase `i`, and its string should just be the item ID; `Damage` and `Count` are separate tags:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:4,Count:1}]}
```

Finally, `Damage` and `Count` are a short and a byte respectively, rather than both integers. This will be auto-corrected when setting them, but for testing you'll need to specify their type.

The full fixed command should be:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:4s,Count:1b}]}
```